# Use jQuery to add scripts to the Head of a document

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a way (using jQuery) that I can add other scripts into the head of a document.

The reason I need to do this is because when building a "template" for a certain web design application I am only allowed to insert 1 js file into the head of the document.

Some features that I would like to add to the design require more than 1 js file so I think I would like to have other js files added to the head of the document as the page loads.
This would allow me to add the features to the design that I want.

I have looked at jQuery's "getScript" call but am not sure if there is a better way to approach this.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about jQuery for this — [Head JS](http://headjs.com/) sounds like it's exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = "http://somedomain.com/script.js";
$("head").append(script);
```

Comment: with jQuery, this can be written in a single line: `$('<script/>', {src: 'http://example.com/foo.js'}).appendTo('head');`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [requireJS](http://requirejs.org/), it's got a lot more features and handles dependencies really well

Answer (score 0):

KulerGary,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('head').append("<script src='file.js' type='text/javascript'></script>");
});
```

I can't test but think its work.

Cya.